# How to handle PSQLException upper(bytea) problem on non-required parameter in Spring data jpa & jpql Query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have this request in a Spring repository

```java
    @Query("Select l from Loan l WHERE (:status is null or l.currentStatus = upper(:status)) and (:id is null or  l.user.id = :id)")
    List<Loan> findByCurrentStatusAndUserId(@Param("status") String status, @Param("id")Long id);
```

that is suppose to ignore the parameters if they are null, except that it sends me an :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: la fonction upper(bytea) n'existe pas
(function upper(bytea) doesn't exists)
```

if my status parameter is null. 
Which doesn't make sense to me. If it's null it shouldn't be tested, it's the whole point of putting ":status is null" no ?
How can i handle that without making a big conditions in my business layer to test my parameters before ?

Comment: If I understand, you want to avoid that problem without using `:status is null`

Comment: i want that it makes the upper(:status) just if status is not null, and that if status is null it doesn't take it in consideration in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using upper function over a parameter that is null because postgreSql interprete it like `upper(null)` regardless your null condition, there are some relative questions without a solution in the Query, so I recommend that you apply the upper in the column (not the parameter) and make the upper sentence to the param from java:

```
@Query("Select l from Loan l WHERE (:status is null or upper(l.currentStatus) = :status) and (:id is null or  l.user.id = :id)")
List<Loan> findByCurrentStatusAndUserId(@Param("status") String status, @Param("id")Long id);
```

As I just said, it should work if you make the upper in the parameter before call this query.

(you can verify this problem by just deleting the `upper` in the query and sending again a null value)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i know why the exception is happening (maybe i was not clear in my question), and i was wondering if there is a way to get over it without changing my java call, otherwise there is not much sense to put these ":status is null". I would like to avoid testing the parameter. But if i have to, i will !

Comment: no, it does have sense to put your null validation, the problem is that when the clause is created (for example with null) it remains like `where null is null or l.status = upper(null)` so I think postgress evaluate the whole condition, so when it evaluate the upper(null) is when the exception is raised

Comment: yes unfortunately i think so too. Thanks for help !